# Google FireStore QuerySnapshot not returning newly added documents?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

For learning purposes, I created an android app and tried to fetch documents from Google Firestore, it worked fine and I was able to read data but later, when I added more documents in the Firestore console, the code is running but still returning me old records. Newly added documents are not returned by QuerySnapshot. I doubt, if it could be any cache issue or if is there any setting that I should change to read the latest documents or to avoid cached records?
any suggestion?

Below is the code snippet, I was considering reading the Documents -

```
            db.collection("posts")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = task.getResult();

                        // Iterate over the documents in the snapshot
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : querySnapshot) {
                              String title = document.getString("title");
                              // printing title in logs
                         }
                       } else{
                             // some else part
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: I don't understand what you expect this code to do that's different than what you observe. Are you expecting a new document to automatically run your completion listener again?  That's not going to happen if you use `get()`. You need to use a realtime listener instead. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Newly added documents are not returned by QuerySnapshot.

That's the expected behavior. As @DougStevenson mentioned in his comment, that's not possible when you're using [Query#get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#get()). This method reads that data only once. This means that you aren't notified about any change that is happening on the server. What you are looking for, is a [real-time listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#java). In code that would be:

```
db.collection("posts").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value,
                                @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                if (e != null) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
                    return;
                }

                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : value) {
                    String title = document.getString("title");
                    if (title != null) {
                        Log.d(TAG, title);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```